# Minimize the running window of a child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, spawn

Is it possible for node.js to minimize the window of a child process that was launched with spawn(), exec() or execFile()? I am launching an application with it that does not allow to be minimized on launch (even making a shortcut and setting the launch options to minimized doesn't make it so), so I'm wondering if node can somehow manually minimize the child after it is running.

I haven't really found anything in the node.js documentation about it, nor other answers. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Windows thing? On Linux, spawning a new process does not result in new windows opening.

Comment: Well, the new process is precisely an application that runs in a window, notably a game that is meant to run in the background as a server.